# Creating a custom authentication with Acegi/Spring Security

Tags: spring-security

I'm having trouble discovering exactly what I need to implement in order to use a custom authentication method with my web application using Spring Security. I have a Grails application with the Spring Security plugin that currently uses the standard user/password authentication with a browser form. This is working correctly.

I need to implement a mechanism alongside of this that implements a type of [MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_authentication_code) authentication. If the HTTP request contains several parameters (e.g. a user identifier, timestamp, signature, etc.) I need to take those parameters, perform some hashing and signature/timestamp comparisons, and then authenticate the user.

I'm not 100% sure where to start with this. What Spring Security classes do I need to extend/implement? I have read the [Reference Documentation](http://www.acegisecurity.org/guide/springsecurity.html) and have an okay understanding of the concepts, but am not really sure if I need a Filter or Provider or Manager, or where/how exactly to create [Authentication](http://static.springframework.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/Authentication.html) objects. I've messed around trying to extend [AbstractProcessingFilter](http://static.springframework.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/ui/AbstractProcessingFilter.html) and/or implement [AuthenticationProvider](http://static.springframework.org/spring-security/site/apidocs/org/springframework/security/providers/AuthenticationProvider.html), but I just get caught up understanding how I make them all play nicely.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Implement a custom `AuthenticationProvider` which gets all your authentication information from the `Authentication`: `getCredentials()`, `getDetails()`, and `getPrincipal()`.

   Tie it into your Spring Security authentication mechanism using the following configuration snippet:

```xml
<bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="com.example.MyAuthenticationProvider">
    <security:custom-authentication-provider />
</bean>
```

2. This step is optional, if you can find a suitable one from standard implementations. If not, implement a class extending the `Authentication` interface on which you can put your authentication parameters:

   ```
   (e.g. a user identifier, timestamp, signature, etc.)
   ```
3. Extend a custom `SpringSecurityFilter` which ties the above two classes together. For example, the Filter might get the `AuthenticationManager` and call `authenticate()` using your implementation of `Authentication` as input.

   You can extend [AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/~tag=3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-security/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java?r=6ac858814407cee65e3c30779cb271ecaf3abd19) as a start.

   You can reference [UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter](https://fisheye.springsource.org/browse/~tag=3.0.5.RELEASE/spring-security/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java?hb=true) which extends `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter`. `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` implements the standard Username/Password Authentication.
4. Configure your Spring Security to add or replace the standard `AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER`. For Spring Security Filter orders, see http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#filter-stack

   Here is a configuration snippet for how to replace it with your implementation:

```xml
<beans:bean id="myFilter" class="com.example.MyAuthenticationFilter">
    <custom-filter position="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER"/>
</beans:bean>
```

Comment: I think you need to use the PRE_AUTH_FILTER position instead of AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER. Also, you may want to look at this tutorial for an implementation of authentication in Google AppEngine: http://blog.springsource.com/2010/08/02/spring-security-in-google-app-engine/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of securityContext.xml configuration file using custom autenticationFilter (extending AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER) and authenticationProvider. The user authentication data is provided by jdbc connection. Configuration is for Spring Security 2.0.x

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <sec:global-method-security />

 <sec:http auto-config="false" realm="CUSTOM" create-session="always" servlet-api-provision="true"
  entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" access-denied-page="/notauthorized.xhtml"
  session-fixation-protection="migrateSession">
  <sec:port-mappings>
   <sec:port-mapping http="80" https="443" />
  </sec:port-mappings>

  <sec:anonymous granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" username="Anonymous" />
  <sec:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS, ROLE_USER" />

  <sec:logout logout-url="/logoff" logout-success-url="/home.xhtml" invalidate-session="false" />

 </sec:http>

 <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.ui.webapp.AuthenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint">
  <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.xhtml" />
  <property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="mypackage.CustomAuthenticationProcessingFilter">
  <sec:custom-filter position="AUTHENTICATION_PROCESSING_FILTER" />
  <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/" />
  <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/logon" />
  <property name="authenticationFailureUrl" value="/loginError.xhtml" />
  <property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="false" />
  <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
 </bean>

 <jee:jndi-lookup id="securityDataSource" jndi-name="jdbc/DB_DS" /> 

 <bean id="myUserDetailsService" class="mypackage.CustomJdbcDaoImpl">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="securityDataSource" />
  <property name="rolePrefix" value="ROLE_" />
 </bean>

 <bean id="apcAuthenticationProvider" class="mypackage.CustomDaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <property name="userDetailsService" ref="myUserDetailsService" />
  <sec:custom-authentication-provider />
 </bean>

 <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager">
  <property name="providers">
   <list>
    <ref local="apcAuthenticationProvider" />
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have recently put up a sample application that does custom authentication with Spring Security 3.
The source code is [here](http://code.google.com/p/tinywebgears-samples/source/browse/trunk/customauth/).
More details are in [this blog post](http://beansgocrazy.blogspot.com/2011/07/custom-authentication-with-spring.html).