# How to switch security model in runtime with spring security?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-ldap, spring-oauth2

How can I switch security model in runtime so that

1. an existing spring security component can produce an `Authentication`, and
2. an existing spring security component can validate the `Authentication`

I think I resolved **(2)** but cannot quite figure out **(1)**.

---

Spring Security configuration

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/**").authenticated().and()
            .addFilterBefore(switchingFilter);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(switchingAuthenticationProvider);
    }

    @Bean
    public SwitchingAuthenticationProvider switchingAuthenticationProvider() {
        return new SwitchingAuthenticationProvider();
    }

    @Bean
    public SwitchingFilter switchingFilter() {
        return new SwitchingFilter();
    }
}
```

The `SwitchingAuthenticationProvider` is straight forward: simply delegate to some other `AuthenticationProvder` (i.e., LDAP/OAUTH2 or otherwise)

(inspired by [Switching authentication approaches at runtime with Spring Security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279621/switching-authentication-approaches-at-runtime-with-spring-security)).

```
public class SwitchingAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    private AuthenticationProvider[] authProviders = // ...

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return authProvider[i].authenticate(authentication);
    }
}
```

But what creates the `Authentication`? As I understand it one option is to let the `GenericFilterBean` create the `Authentication` as illustrated below.

```
public class SwitchingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private AuthProviderService authProviders = // ...

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        Authentication authentication = authProviders.getAuthentication(request);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
   }
}
```

... where an `AuthProviderService` would delegate to something that creates an  `authentication`. But how can I plug it with e.g., the equivalent of `HttpSecurity#httpBasic()` or `HttpSecurity#openIdLogin()`?

---

Bonus question: What's the difference between `HttpSecurity#authenticationProvider(..)` and `AuthenticationManagerBuilder.authenticationProvider(..)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears the `Filter` ***is*** responsible to create the `Authentication` (not sure if anything else is too).

The `AnonymousAuthenticationFilter` as an example

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                createAuthentication((HttpServletRequest) req));
}
```

Similar I think the `SwitchingFilter` should be similar to `SwitchingAuthenticationProvider`

```
public class SwitchingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private Filter[] filters = // ...

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        filters[i].doFilter(request, response, chain);
        // do filterChain.doFilter(request, response); ??
   }
}
```

.. for some mechanism of selecting a suitable index `i`.